# AChartEngine Plotting, ArrayList indexing

Tags: java, android, arraylist, plot, achartengine

I am new to android, and I have to create an app that plots data. One set of data is about 7000 data point, and I've been using AChartEngine. I am using an ArrayList to hold the data.

```
ArrayList<Double> forehead = new ArrayList<Double>();

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getforeDataset() {

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        XYSeries firstSeries = new XYSeries("Forehead");
        for (int i = 0; i < forehead.size(); i++)
            firstSeries.add(i, forehead.get(i));
        dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);

        return dataset;
```

this is where I add data into the ArrayList, a sample string that would be read in is:

"02888  0   096 098 080"

```
private void getIntegerArray(ArrayList<String> stringArray) {

        for (String s:stringArray){
            String[] str = s.split("\t");

            forehead.add(Double.parseDouble(str[3]));

        }               

    }

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getforeRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
        r.setFillPoints(false);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        return renderer;
    }
```

plotting

```
mChartView2 = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), getforeDataset(),
                    getforeRenderer());
layout2.addView(mChartView2);
```

Here is my application and no data is displayed, how can I display the 'forehead' ArrayList?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjp0d.jpg

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanS How can I display the data from the ArrayList

Comment: @DanS I believe my error is in the XYSeries, and the type of Double I am inputting. I still have not resolved it, but any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
String[] str = s.split(" ");
```

instead of

```
 String[] str = s.split("\t");
```

I think you are not getting the values as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response @keshav, I was able to plot it using with s.split("\\s+")